# Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.date')

Tags: javascript, html

I keep getting this error in my code how I could fix it

```
// Personal API Key for OpenWeatherMap API
const COUNTRY = 'us';
const API_KEY = 'some key';
const BASE_URL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
const MY_SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';

// Event listener to add function to existing HTML DOM element
document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', performAction);

/* Function called by event listener */
function performAction(e) {
  const zip = document.getElementById('zip').value;
  const feelings = document.getElementById('feelings').value;
  getWeather(zip, feelings);
}

/* Function to GET Web API Data*/
/* Function to POST data */
/* Function to GET Project Data */
const getWeather = async (zip, feelings) => {

  const res =
    fetch(`${BASE_URL}?APPID=${API_KEY}&zip=${zip},${COUNTRY}`) // GET
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        // Add data
        const tempKelvin = data.main.temp;
        const d = new Date();
        const formattedDate = d.getMonth() + '.' + d.getDate() + '.' + d.getFullYear();
        return postData(`${MY_SERVER_URL}/addData`, { // POST
          date: formattedDate,
          temperature: tempKelvin,
          feelings: feelings,
        });
      })
      .then(() => fetch(`${MY_SERVER_URL}/all`)) // GET returns the fetch promise
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(allData => {
        // *********************************
        // here is my problem
        // *********************************
        const data = allData[allData.length - 1];
        document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = data.date;
        document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = formatTemperature(data.temperature);
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data.feelings;
      });
}

function formatTemperature(tempKelvin) {
  const celcius = tempKelvin - 273.15;
  const fahrenheit = celcius * (9/5) + 32;
  return `${celcius.toFixed(0)} C/${fahrenheit.toFixed(1)} F`;
}

function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  });
}
```

Comment: Just a little warning, don't post your API keys public. Somethings are best kept secret

Comment: From the error, you api response for fetch(`${MY_SERVER_URL}/all`) should be something empty. Try logging the response to find out

Answer (score 0):

You response seems to be returning empty array. As a quick fix you can simply add a check for that

```js
// Event listener to add function to existing HTML DOM element
document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', performAction);

/* Function called by event listener */
function performAction(e) {
  const zip = document.getElementById('zip').value;
  const feelings = document.getElementById('feelings').value;
  getWeather(zip, feelings);
}

/* Function to GET Web API Data*/
/* Function to POST data */
/* Function to GET Project Data */
const getWeather = async (zip, feelings) => {

  const res =
    fetch(`${BASE_URL}?APPID=${API_KEY}&zip=${zip},${COUNTRY}`) // GET
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        // Add data
        const tempKelvin = data.main.temp;
        const d = new Date();
        const formattedDate = d.getMonth() + '.' + d.getDate() + '.' + d.getFullYear();
        return postData(`${MY_SERVER_URL}/addData`, { // POST
          date: formattedDate,
          temperature: tempKelvin,
          feelings: feelings,
        });
      })
      .then(() => fetch(`${MY_SERVER_URL}/all`)) // GET returns the fetch promise
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(allData => {
        if(!allData.length) {
          console.error("Empty array");
          return;
        }
        *italic* >quote here is the problem I have
        const data = allData[allData.length - 1];
        document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = data.date;
        document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = formatTemperature(data.temperature);
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data.feelings;
      });
}

function formatTemperature(tempKelvin) {
  const celcius = tempKelvin - 273.15;
  const fahrenheit = celcius * (9/5) + 32;
  return `${celcius.toFixed(0)} C/${fahrenheit.toFixed(1)} F`;
}

function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  });
}
```